# WordPress POST request returns entire HTML page instead of JSON response

Tags: html, wordpress, post, request

When I send a POST request to my local dev install of WordPress under MAMP 4.1 (Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra) It returns the entire HTML of the home page rather than the expected response. The behavior seems similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205447/why-wordpress-ajax-request-returns-the-entire-html-page-instead-of-json-result) except that I'm sure that the cause is not in the syntax of the request nor the WooCommerce-related plugin (NSP-Code Software License) that receives it (REST is enabled).

I've reinstalled MAMP, tried MAMP Pro, and recreated a simple WordPress test site several times, to no avail. An identical dev site on my laptop (MacBook Pro with same environment) works perfectly with requests sent from either PHP scripts or the Postman app. Postman does offer a clue, though, among the headers of the reply on my desktop install:

> Link →http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/; rel="https://api.w.org/"
>
> Link →http://localhost:8888/wordpress/; rel=shortlink
>
> Server →Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/5.4.45 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0

My ISP has PHP 5.4.45 so I'm targeting that, although I get the same result with PHP 7.1. Is there anything in the local dev environment that could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [DesktopServer](https://serverpress.com) to replace MAMP solved the problem. It's not as configurable as MAMP, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your functions properly and your function must be like this in proper way
In php file

```
add_action("wp_ajax_submit_form_data", "new_submit_form_data" );
function new_submit_form_data(){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        // your code to manipulate data
    }
    die();
}
```

In jquery file

```
jQuery("#input-id").live("click", function(){
var id = jQuery(".textinput").val();
jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType:"json",  
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {"id":id,action:"submit_form_data"},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

After that view the response and do whatever you want to do with the response data.